# How to speed up results from 'ls' on a network drive under ubuntu running in WSL

Tags: sed, ksh, ls

I have noticed that if I run '/bin/ls --color=always --file-type -aFC' on my network drive, that it takes anywhere from 39s to 57s to complete. I assumed the problem was just the colorizing. If I run '/bin/ls --color=never --file-type -aC', the command takes less than 2s. The same, if I run the same command and pipe it to sed to add some pretty colors. However, if I create a shell function that runs the same ls command to sed, it now takes close to a minute. It's the same if I make a shell script to pipe ls to sed. It runs great on the command line, however. I also notice that if I run '/bin/ls --color=never --file-type -aC *.ps1', it takes over a minute.

I read somewhere that exa was a faster, more powerful ls, but it also takes close to a minute to run. Why is a bare ls so fast and an ls with arguments so slow? Is there anything that I can do to speed things up? Is there any way to keep the speed of a bare ls command while still being able to pipe the output to sed?

I'm running ksh93 version 1.0.6 on Ubuntu running under WSL. Thanks!

Some examples:

Command line:

```
-->     time /bin/ls --color=never --file-type -C |  sed -E $'s/([[:graph:]]+ ?)+\\//\e[01m\e[34m&\e[0m\e[37m/g'

real    0m00.43s
user    0m00.00s
sys     0m00.00s
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/ksh -p

/bin/ls --color=never --file-type -aFC | sed -E $'s/([[:graph:]]+ ?)+\\//\e[01m\e[34m&\e[0m\e[37m/g'

-->     cat ~/bin/colorls
/s/wastebasket/sam $ time ~/bin/colorls


real    1m12.73s
user    0m00.00s
sys     0m00.04s
```

Comment: Does the question have to do with software development?

Comment: The problem is certainly that the tool run a stat request for each file. The thing is network drives tends to be inherently slow : each request travel the network and sometime they cannot be batched nor executed all at once or need a synchronization for each request regarding the protocol used. The key here is the protocol. If concurrent requests are possible, then you can try to run stat on each file in parallel to see if it is faster. For the listing you can use lower-level APIs (the OS ones are not always the fastest). Note that if you just want a tool for that, then this is off-topic here.

Comment: `strace -f` will give you an idea of the differences. For example, compare `ls -p` and `ls -d *`. The former has a handful of calls to `getdents64()`; the latter has numerous calls to `statx()`. The cumulative roundtrips for all calls causes the latency.

Comment: "if I create a shell function that runs the same ls command to sed, it now takes close to a minute" - Is it really the same identical  ls command? Please add your function to the question.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice WSL. I don't know what functions strace will show there. But I expect the quantities will be similar.

Comment: I once had a similar problem. The network drive had for over 150.000 files in one directory, files from 3 years of history. Old files where not needed, business only needed one month. Deleting older files helped a lot!